# An UITabBar like Tweetbot3

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I would like to know if someone have an idea about how Tapbots made Tweetbot3 TabBar?

In my app, there will be many TabItems, and I don't want the "More" Tab (by default), but I'm very interested to have a similar system to Tweetbot, with a "picker" which opens on long press gesture on a `TabBarItem`.

But, I'm hesitating on the method. It's better to apply a customized `UITabBar` class, or to totally "deconstruct" the `UITabBarController` (to use a `UIViewController` and a custom "tabbar")?

Comment: Most likely, that's a full custom view that only resembles a `UITabBar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having created many custom tab bars, I'd start by subclassing UITabBar and UITabBarController. I wouldn't expect any roadblocks with this approach.

You may want to move the default buttons around and then add some custom buttons. Send a message back to the tab bar controller and let it display the popup choices view.